# I want to make command python3 to run python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using Mac OS Mojave version 10.14.2
I just installed python3.7 and uninstalled python3.6.
Then, the following result occurs

```
$ python3
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: No such file or directory
$ which python3
-bash: type: python3: not found
$ which python3.7
python3.7 is /usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

I want to make the python3 command runs python3.7 but I am very confused of the setting of python.
I searched on Google but I couldn't solve it.
Could you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: perhaps not the ideal solution but an easy work around is creating an alias in your `bashrc`. `alias python3='python3.7'`

Comment: It is not a good idea to replace the system installed Python interpreter as some OS functions depend on that specific release. It is better to keep both versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bad soft link since you removed `python3`.

Check out where `python3` is by

```
which python3
```

Then use the return of that output to see what it's currently pointing to

```
ls -la $(which python3)
```

Replace the bad `python3` softlink with the correct `python3.7`

```
ln -sf $(which python3.7) /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Test out the version

```
python3 --version
```

In the future, check out [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) because it will make installing new versions of python and switching between versions much easier.